# "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255" cuando intento instalar Kivy 1.11.1

Tags: python, windows, kivy, python-3.8

Python deja de funcionar cuando intento instalar Kivy==1.11.1 con pip en mi Windows 7. Esto es lo que me aparece:

> ```
> Building wheel for kivy (setup.py) ... error
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 255:
> ```

Answer (score 0):

La última versión estable de Kivy a día de hoy (1.11.1) que es la disponible en pypi [no es compatible con Python 3.8.x](http://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563) y el problema no se va a corregir hasta la nueva versión estable de kivy en principio. Tienes dos opciones:

- Usar Python 3.7.x
- Usar Python 3.8 pero instalando la versión en desarrollo de Kivy (v2.0.0rc1 a día de hoy) que ya tiene el problema corregido (teniendo en cuenta que no es una versión estable y puede tener bugs):

  ```
  python -m pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple
  ```

Comment: gracias me funciono instalando python 3.7